# SQL: get unique rows based on concatenation of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL statement that will derive a list of rows that are unique based on the concatenation of two columns.

Given this set of data, I want the result to remove duplicate rows where a duplicate is defined as the concatenation of Column1 and Column2.

Things:

```
ID    Column1    Column2        Column3
1        a          z              L
2        b          y              G
3        b          y              G
4        a          y              H
5        a          z              L
```

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( Column1 || Column2 ) FROM things
```

Result:

```
az
by
ay
```

This works fine, however it only derives a list of the unique concatenation of Column1 and Column2,

I need the Column3 returned as well, as in:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
    a         z            L
    b         y            G   
    a         y            H
```

This does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( Column1 || Column2 ), Column3 FROM things
```

as it returns more rows than needed.

How would I construct an SQL statement to derive the desired result of unique rows based on the concatenation of two columns?  It does not matter if Column3 is not unique.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the concatenation is avoidable. Why not just GROUP BY both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not care about the values of `Column3` how they come, you can use group by

```
select 
Column1,
Column2,
Column3
from things
group by Column1,Column2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want an arbitrary value for `Column3`:

```
select column1, column2, min(Column3)
from table t
group by column1, column2;
```

You could use `group_concat()` to get all the values.

Comment: could you please provide an example of group_concat() and its result?